# Erro de redirecionamento

Tags: cakephp, htaccess, redirecionamento

No servidor de um cliente tem um projeto em CakePHP, eu criei uma pasta chamada **halldafama** na raiz do servidor. Preciso acesse essa pasta, só que ao tentar acessar me retorna: `Error: The requested address '//halldafama/' was not found on this server.` sendo que essa pasta **halldafama** não tem nada haver com o CakePHP.

Meu HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Já verificou a permissão da pasta?

Comment: ARRUMADO!: Ajustei colocando os arquivos na pasta webroot